# copy one vector element and second vector in to third vector and avoiding duplicates

Tags: c++

We want to copy first vector and second vector in to third vector while avoiding duplicates.

```
vector<Type>vect1,vect2,vect3;
 for(int i=0;i<vect1.size();i++){
      vect3.push_back(vect1[i]);
    for(int j=0;j<vect2.size();j++){
      if(vect1[i].name==vect2[j].name)
       break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Good for you! So... why are you writing here? what is your question? Does the code you presented result in what you want?

Comment: @KamilCuk, can not get what I want,  getting logical error. any alternative?

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the vectors? A `std::set` could be useful too

Comment: @ Damien, we have structure type data. only allowed vector.

Comment: copy `v1` and `v2` in `v3`, sort `v3`, remove duplicated consecutive elements.
`auto v3 = v1; copy(begin(v2), end(v2), back_inserter(v3)); sort(begin(v3), end(v3)); v3.erase(unique(begin(v3), end(v3)), end(v3))`

Comment: Can `Vect1`/`Vect2` has duplicate on their own?

Comment: sounds like [`set_union`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union)

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
for (auto data : v1)
{
    v3.push_back(data);
}

for (auto data : v2)
{
    auto it = std::find(v3.begin(), v3.end(), data);
    if (it == v3.end())
    {
        v3.push_back(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: First loop can simply be `v3 = v1;`

Comment: and that assumes no duplicates in `v1` itself.

Comment: @Sourabh, getting error like expected initializer before ':' token

Comment: @Excoder: Do you compile with pre-C++11 standard?

Answer (score 1):

Your code suggests that you want to copy all elements from `v1` into `v3` (unconditionaly) and all elements from `v2` that are not in `v1`.

The following code should do it:

```
// if v3 is initially empty, you can just do: v3 = v1;
// copy elements from v1:
for (const Type& elt: v1) {
    v3.push_back(elt);
}
// v2:
for (const Type& elt: v2) {
    if (std::find(v1.begin(), v1.end(), elt) != v1.end()) {  // test if contained in v1
        v3.push_back(elt);
    }
}
```

But searching in a vector is linear. If `v1` and `v2` are large, using a `set::set` or `std::unordered_set` could speed up the operation.